# Django 2: How to loop through form fields where string not in

Tags: python, django, forms

In a template html, I would like to loop through each form field and display the form if e.g. '_description' is not in the form field name.

I then want to display an extra, associated field next to it. e.g. something like:

```
{% for field in form.fields %}
    {% if "_description" not in field %}
         {{ field }}
         {{ field + "_description"}} <-- getting the associated form field to display

{% endfor %}
```

Can this sort of logic be done in Django?

Comment: What do you mean by associated field?

Comment: I think it would make more sense to tune the field names in the the form's model definition. With your scheme, how do you recover the appropriate names when processing the posted data?